# Add some elements in code to other layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two classes: one is activity and second is extend LinearLayout. This is code for activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

    private Button button;
    private ClassTabs tab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        tab = (ClassTabs) inflater.inflate(R.id.tab, null);
        tab.addTab(button);

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.actionbartest.ClassTabs
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is class extend LinearLayout:

```
public class ClassTabs extends LinearLayout{

    Button button;
    public ClassTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }
    public ClassTabs(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabview, this);
        setupViewItems();

    }

    private void setupViewItems() {
        button = new Button(getContext());      
    }

     public void addTab(Button child){
            LinearLayout tab = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
            tab.addView(child);
     }

}
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blue"
   >





</LinearLayout>
```

Now as you can see I have method to add some child to this layout. I want to add some buttons to this layout from activity. In that solution I get nullPointer exception. How I can add some elements from activity using method from other class, in this case `addTab()`?

Edit: This is what I want: I have one activity in this case "second activity" where I want use layout from "ClassTabs". I ClassTabs I want to have method which will add button to layout which is inflated in activity. I want run activity where in layout I use part of layout from ClassTab. Next step is add butto to this inflated layout from ClassTab but I want do that in code in "second activity". I want to have method in ClassTab to added buttons because I want to use that method in other activities.

Comment: What is the line you're getting the NullPointerException on?

Answer (score 0):

First of All you don't have to extend a LinearLayout just to add children to it dynamically, as long as you don'y want to ovverride a certain behaviour for it, don't extend it, instead use an ordinary linearLayout and add children to it using **addview()** Method.

In your code:

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Then In your Activity:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
                 super.onCreate(bundle);
                 linearLayout = (LinearLayou) findViewById(R.layout.linearLayout);    
                }
```

Then When you want to add any View "TextView / Button ....." just use:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
..... // modify the button
linearLayout.addChild(button);
```

Comment: I can't use your method, because I need to use method addButton from other class

Comment: you can, just pass your activity to that class , and when you want to add the button call .... activity.addButton(Button button)
where addButton is a function in your activity that adds the button to the layout

Comment: I want to do that in opposite way, because I want to use that in others activities

Comment: Please add what you want to achieve exactly to the question text if you want anyone to help you